# WPF обработка нажатия клавиш вне окна

Tags: c#, wpf

Делаю приложение на WPF. Мне нужно, чтобы даже если окно не в фокусе, то оно все равно могло реагировать на нажатие клавиши Ctrl.

Comment: Вам нужно использовать хуки https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291448/how-do-i-detect-keypress-while-not-focused

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать глобальные системные хуки для перехвата нажатий клавиш.

[В этой статье](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/274003/global-hotkeys-in-wpf) Henning Dieterichs создал для WPF класс для глобальных хуков, посмотрим как его использовать.

Копируем код основных классов из статьи. Далее (если нужна дополнительная логика) нам нужно унаследоваться от класса `HotKey`. У меня получилось следующее:

```
public class CustomHotKey : HotKey
{
    private Action<Key, ModifierKeys> _onHotKeyPressHandler;
    public CustomHotKey(Key key, ModifierKeys modifiers, Action<Key, ModifierKeys> onHotKeyPressAction = null)
        : base(key, modifiers, true)
    {
        _onHotKeyPressHandler = onHotKeyPressAction;
    }

    protected override void OnHotKeyPress()
    {
       _onHotKeyPressHandler?.Invoke(Key, Modifiers);
        base.OnHotKeyPress();
    }
}
```

Класс `CustomHotKey` принимает в конструкторе клавиши, нажатие которых нужно перехватить, а также делегат, который будет вызываться для обработки нажатия этих клавиш.

Далее на событие `Loaded` окна вешаем обработчик, в нем создаем экземпляр `HotKeyHost` и указываем какие клавиши или сочетания клавиш нам нужно отслеживать.

Если вам нужно отслеживать нажатие <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, то первым параметром передаем `Key.None`, вторым - `ModifierKeys.Control` и третьим - метод, который будет обрабатывать нажатие клавиш. Для примера я также добавил код для сочетания <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.

Вот что вышло:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var hotKeyHost = new HotKeyHost((HwndSource) PresentationSource.FromVisual(this));
    hotKeyHost.AddHotKey(new CustomHotKey(Key.None, ModifierKeys.Control, OnHotkeyPress));
    hotKeyHost.AddHotKey(new CustomHotKey(Key.A, ModifierKeys.Control, OnHotkeyPress));
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]